# Sci-Kit Learn: getting value from matrix generated by CountVectorizer.fit_transofrm() (PYTHON)

Tags: python, matrix, count, scikit-learn

My code is this one:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
new_text = ["with with hello hello hello house"]
X_new_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(new_text)


i = count_vect.vocabulary_.get('hello')
print(X_new_counts.shape)
c = X_new_counts.getcol(0)
print(c)
```

The matrix generated by `X_new_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(new_text)` has got this shape: (1, 3)

with `i = count_vect.vocabulary_.get('hello')`, i get the index in the vocabulary of *hello*.

My **goal** is getting the value from this matrix of the index relative count. How i can? If I type:

```
value = X_new_counts.getcol(i)
```

it returns:

> (0, 0)      3

where "3" is the correct value, but i don't want (0,0). So, how can i get only this value from the matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X_new_counts is a (sparse) matrix so you can get the values in i, j using:

```
X_new_counts[i, j]
```